# using odbc instead of sql server connections in c#

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, odbc

Greeting and Salutations!
I work in an environment where I have a development server, QA server and a production server. I've recently ran into issues because I would like to work locally and have my local development connect to our development server. When I deploy to our development server I want the data connection to continue to connect to our development server but then when I deploy to our QA or production, I want it to connect to the database sitting on that current server.

I've come up with a solution that using an ODBC data source to connect to the SQL instead of using standard SQL data connections is the easiest way to manage this. This means changing my connection string, along with using odbc ado.net instead of SQL ado.net.

My question is, is there any downside, limitations or performance loss with using ODBC connections over standard SQL connections?  Will this prevent me from using LINQ / Entity framework later on?

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: Is there a reason not to store your connection string in config files, and just modify the config file based on environment?  You post doesn't explain why a standard sql connection string (again- modified for environment) won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out on my own. I did a benchmark of the code using the SQL driver against the same exact code using the ODBC driver.

My results are below.

- ODBC DRIVER: 100% connection success. Average duration 796
  Millisecond.
- SQL DRIVER: 100% connection success!  Average duration
  641 Millisecond.

The ODBC driver performs slightly slower. I still might use because this benchmark was again 20 thousand records so the difference should be very minimal.

Thanks you all for your help!

Paul

Answer (score 1):

Usually the downgrade in performance is only when creating the connection to the database.  That operation is intensive for all provider types.

Someone please correct me if I'm wrong, but as of .NET4 Microsoft has created an Oracle driver which I believe allows LINQ to SQL.  I know it was in the works at one point and I know the Oracle driver is for .NET4, so I'm assuming that's the same one.

However, LINQ to Entities is db agnostic so as long as you stick with that you should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

I can't discuss the performance, but do you store the connection string to the database in a configuration file?  It seems to me that changing the connection mechanism is the more complicated solution to changing the connection string to find the correct server.

Comment: It's stored in the web.config file. It's not really a big deal to change it whenever we deploy but our team has restrictions about our development, QA and production server's having code that's not identical. Using ODBC data sources fixes this problem. It's not a very difficult thing to impliment, in fact I've already done it I was just looking to see if anyone knew if there was a downside to using odbc drivers over SQLServer drivers when connecting to SQLServer.